# Downloading Intra-Day Data From StockRageous... without link

Tags: r, download, stocks, rcurl, stockquotes

I am wondering if it is possible to download Intra-day data using R from the following link:

< http://www.stockrageous.com/charting.jsp?Symbol=NFLX >

The problem is that in order to do so one must manually go to the `Data` tab and then select the range and the `Time` interval desired. I want to automate this process as it can take a long time to download intra-day stock quotes. Can anyone guide me through this process to see if it is even possible?

*UPDATE*
I have found the link to the download but I cannot access directly... is there any way I can get to the data?

< http://www.stockrageous.com/datadownload?symbolType=stock&check=no&symbol=msft&startDate=2013-08-20&endDate=2014-02-20&intervalType=Intraday&intervalList=1 >

Comment: You might be able to use `RCurl` to mock up the HTTP post from the `datadownload` form, but it looks like it's intended to prevent remote downloads (i.e. skipping the entry page) - which it probably fair enough given it's a free service!

Comment: Your updated link appears to be incorrect: "Sorry. You cannot access this link directly. Please go to the data tab in charting page and try again."

Comment: @Troy Thanks for your input. When I use `RCurl`, `getURLContent()` more specificly, I do not get anything. Am I using the wrong Function?

Comment: @Thomas I tested the URL with `url.exists()` and it comes back as TRUE but like Troy mentioned, The site intended to prevent remote downloads I suppose but I want to get around that if possible?

Comment: Hi @Jason, probably you would need to use `RCurl::postForm` since it's a post, but when I tried it, I got the same message so looks like they have deliberately blocked indirect access.